# Android answer button, how to scroll it

Tags: android

I have 4 buttons in my android app. Which have answers on them and when user clicks on button with right answer he goes to next question. Problem i am having is with smaller phones the answer button has less area so the text raps around at the bottom of the button textbox. I have scrolling enabled on the button but when user click on button to scroll down, button is clicked also. Is there a way to solve this? I have searched on google but cant find any solution.

For example question is richest person in the world: answer: Bill Gates. So if button is small it will only show Bill and Gates will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, there is.

You should change your layout for a better user experience, usually button labels aren't good to write long informations.

your "QuestionActivity" (which i suppose it is like a "Who wants to be a millionaire?" template) should have 2 components

1. TextView, where you put the question
2. ListView, where you put the N answers (from 1 to n) which is natively scrollable vertically and so you can keep much more space for each answer

you just have to use an ArrayAdapter and you're pretty much done with a much better solution.

Comment: So if i understand right listbox you can scroll vertically and when you click on it will act like button?  Also what will ArrayAdapter do?

Comment: you have to set up an "OnItemClickListener" on your ListView. The adapter provides the data (your answer) to the ListView to allow the correct rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create your own Button control and implement the onTouch behaviour.

But instead of doing so, why don't you create a list of items, where aeach item is an answer.
The list is scrollable by default. And items can be hooked up to click events. You can even make your list items look like buttons, with a proper selector.

Comment: No it is not a list. It is like two line answer all same thing. For example question is richest person in the world: answer: Bill Gates. So if button is small it will only show Bill and Gates will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I donT think a `ListView` will solve your problem, nor it is necessary. You probably have a fixed number for choices as answers in your mind anyway.

- a.
- b.
- c.

So being able to list *N* answers will only complicate things for you.

> The ListView is natively scrollable

Yes, but the items are not. And thats what you actually need. So keep your prefixed `Buttons`/clickable `TextViews`

---

As for your real problem, which is basically a design/ usability issue, I suggest simply using a different button for selecting the answer to proceed (to the next question ...etc.).

[image]

This way, the unintentional clicks can be recovered ( when user is trying to scroll stuff, change his mind for the answer). You can use `RadioButton` like controls to make sure one option is selected upon *Next* click.

Hope it helps.

Ref: [Image](http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&rlz=1C1ASUT_enPT391PT391&biw=1366&bih=677&tbm=isch&tbnid=5D5rOYObMDo9pM:&imgrefurl=http://trivial-pursuit.en.softonic.com/pocketpc&docid=yPWIb0_wxuTIjM&imgurl=http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/30000/30982/trivial-pursuit-6.jpg&w=400&h=400&ei=wH86T8XDCYGg-AbAl-WsBw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=578&vpy=270&dur=1395&hovh=225&hovw=225&tx=134&ty=156&sig=106442305280248029718&page=1&tbnh=143&tbnw=143&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:14,s:0)

---

**EDIT** Sample code to clarify.. apparently it is needed. Note, it wonT work if you copy-paste.

```
int iSelectedButtonId = 0;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
        ...
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myAwesomeButton1); // and the other buttons..etc
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           button.setBackground(android.Orange); // or smth
           iSelectedButtonId = button.id;

    });

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      // Todo my stuff here instead
     }
    }
```

Comment: But that changes the whole design of the app. I have specially designed buttons for this app.

Comment: It s ok. In the ´onClick´ of your buttons, donT _take action_ (end the quiz, submitting result, going to the next question ..etc :). Just set is as the selected answer. Then onClick of the new button, _take action_.